# Reading byte array in C++

Tags: embedded, c++

I have following code in C++

```
#define NO_SECTORS  4
#define HEADER_SIZE 6
#define SECTOR_SIZE 64

union flash_rec_u{
    struct record{
        union header_u{
            struct header{
                uint32_t sector_number;
                uint16_t no_written_bytes;
            }header_items __attribute__((packed));
            uint8_t header_bytes[HEADER_SIZE];
        }header;
        uint8_t data_bytes[SECTOR_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE];
    }rec_items;
    uint8_t rec_bytes[SECTOR_SIZE];
};

typedef uint8_t SECTOR[SECTOR_SIZE];
typedef SECTOR FLASH[NO_SECTORS];

FLASH flash;

SECTOR initialStateSector_00[SECTOR_SIZE] = { 
    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0x00,
    0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA,
    0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA,
    0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

void PrintSector(uint8_t sector){
  for(uint8_t curByte = 0; curByte < SECTOR_SIZE; curByte++){
    std::cout << std::setw(2);      
    std::cout << showbase << dec;   
    std::cout << hex << (uint16_t)flash[sector][curByte] << ", ";
    if(curByte % 16 == 15){
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
  }
  std::cout << "\n";  
}

void PrintFlash(void){
    for(uint8_t curSector = 0; curSector < NO_SECTORS; curSector++){
        std::cout << "SECTOR: " << (uint16_t)curSector << "\n";
        PrintSector(curSector);
    }
}

void EraseSector(uint16_t sector){
    for(uint16_t curByte = 0; curByte < SECTOR_SIZE; curByte++){
        flash[sector][curByte] = ERASED_BYTE;
    }
}

void EraseFlash(void){
    for(uint16_t curSector = 0; curSector < NO_SECTORS; curSector++){
        EraseSector(curSector);
    }
}

void WriteBytes2Sector(uint8_t sector, uint8_t *srcBytes){
    for(uint16_t curByte = 0; curByte < SECTOR_SIZE; curByte++){
        flash[sector][curByte] = *(srcBytes + curByte);
    }
}

void ReadSector(uint8_t sector, uint8_t *readBytes, uint16_t noBytes2bRead){

    for(uint16_t curSrcByte = 0; curSrcByte < noBytes2bRead; curSrcByte++){
        *(readBytes + curSrcByte) = flash[sector][curSrcByte];
    }
}

void StoreEventLog(uint8_t *eventBytes, uint16_t noEventBytes){

    flash_rec_u buffer;                             


    ReadSector(0, buffer.rec_bytes, 1);    

    for(uint8_t curByte = 0; curByte < SECTOR_SIZE; curByte++){
        std::cout << std::setw(2);      
        std::cout << showbase << dec;   
        std::cout << hex << (uint16_t)(buffer.rec_bytes[curByte]) << ", ";
        if(curByte % 16 == 15){
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    uint8_t bytes2bStored[] = {
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB,
        0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB
    };

    EraseFlash();
    PrintFlash();
    WriteBytes2Sector(0, *initialStateSector_00);
    PrintFlash();

    StoreEventLog(bytes2bStored, sizeof(bytes2bStored));
    PrintFlash();

    return 0;
}
```

The flash content after erasing:

```
SECTOR: 0
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 

SECTOR: 0x1
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 

SECTOR: 0x2
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 

SECTOR: 0x3
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
```

The flash content after writing into the sector 0:

```
SECTOR: 0
0x1,  0,  0,  0, 0x25,  0, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 
0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 
0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 

SECTOR: 0x1
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 

SECTOR: 0x2
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 

SECTOR: 0x3
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
```

Whenever I call the ReadSector function from the StoreEventLog function for reading
content of the sector 0 into temporary variable buffer and then print content of 
the buffer variable I always get totally wrong content:

```
0x1, 0xcb, 0xff, 0xff,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0x67, 0x5b, 0x4c, 0xfe, 0x3,  0,  0,  0, 
0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,0,
```

It seems that the problem is in the ReadSector function, but I don't know where. Could anybody tell me what I do wrong? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Type punning to unions isn't well-defined behavior in C++, which is one of the reasons why that language is unsuitable for embedded/hardware-related programming. It is well-defined in C though, so you could try to convert this snippet to C and re-compile in a C compiler. This code also relies on constructors getting called by the "CRT" during start-up, you should verify that they are indeed called. In addition, you have the struct padding issue in C and C++ both, which will be a problem if this is a 32 bit CPU. You'll have to ensure there's no padding.

Comment: What does this have to do with **Electronic Design?** which is what this site is for.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you very much for your reaction. I haven't taken into account padding at all. Do you have any experience how to solve the padding issue?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The question is obviously about writing a flash driver for a MCU. Hardware-related programming of micrcontrollers is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: @Steve Depends on CPU and compiler. There will some non-standard command for your specific compiler, like for example `#pragma pack(1)`, which enforces no padding. However, this could cause problems with misaligned access. If skipping padding is no option, then you either have to write serialization/de-serialization routines that puts the data in/out of the struct manually. Or alternatively skip the struct entirely in favour of a raw `uint8_t` array.

Comment: But I would start with trying to compile the same code in C, as type punning through union is the most likely culprit.

Comment: @Lundin I have just done some changes regarding the diagnostics printings and recompiled the source code with C compiler. Unfortunately the result is same.

Comment: @Lundin Type punning through a `union` is not the source of problem in this case (simply because the posted code does not use any type punning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing uninitialized (stack) memory.

That's because in `StoreEventLog` you are dumping the contents of a local variable (`buffer`). The contents of `buffer` haven't yet been (fully) initialized.

In your code the call to `ReadSector` only copies the first byte (specified in the last argument of the function call). You probably want to copy the whole sector. Replace ...

`ReadSector(0, buffer.rec_bytes, 1);`

... with ...

`ReadSector(0, buffer.rec_bytes, SECTOR_SIZE);`

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. Do you have any idea what could be wrong in the ReadSector function?

Comment: @Steve There's nothing wrong **in** the function. You simply just told it to only copy the first byte of the "sector". The bug is in the call, not in the function.

Comment: I made the proposed solution clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry for such stupid question. I became totally blind after looking into the code for a long time.